# Docker: split mysql databases into different data volume containers?

Tags: mysql, database, nginx, docker

I have the following Docker containers:

- `web` (nginx)
- `db` (mysql)

The `web` container is linked to the `db` container.  All standard stuff.

For data persistence, I want to take the [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) approach.

I want to be able to run several websites using these 2 containers as the main application containers (well, technically, the `web` container runs the main user-facing application and the `db` sits behind that).

Let's say I have `siteA`, `siteB`, and `siteC` using databases `A`, `B`, and `C` respectively in mysql.

I would like to be able to partition these site's database data into 3 different data volume containers (`dataA`, `dataB`, `dataC`) for portability, and bring them together in a single deployment (one host running `web`, `db`, `dataA`, `dataB`, `dataC` all linked appropriately) when needed.

**Is there a way to partition the separate mysql databases into their own data volume containers for portability?** AFAIK, mysql stores all of it's database data in `/var/lib/mysql` in some fashion that is not transparent in terms of the databases that mysql is storing.

For example, it would be nice if the different databases being stored in mysql were mapped to known directories - in this case, `/var/lib/mysql/A`, `/var/lib/mysql/B`, and `/var/lib/mysql/C`.  This way, all I would have to do persist those directories and mount them in the `db` container.  I don't think this is the case though.

Comment: I guess you want one mysql server process which persist each db in a different directory. I can't find anything like that inside the mysql documentation. Perhaps it's enough to dump the database regular inside those directory and being able to reimport. Otherwise I advice using Luke's  way.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just run multiple instances of the db container? Mapping the dir's as needed.

```
docker run -d -v /var/lib/mysql/A:/var/lib/mysql --name dbA my_docker/my_awesome_mysql
docker run -d -v /var/lib/mysql/B:/var/lib/mysql --name dbB my_docker/my_awesome_mysql
docker run -d -v /var/lib/mysql/C:/var/lib/mysql --name dbC my_docker/my_awesome_mysql
```

This would help if you ever needed to move dbA only to another host.

Comment: The biggest reason I would not want to do this is that it would complicate the links with my `web` container (with a single `db` container, the link is simple).  With 3 database containers, how would the linking work?  Also, If all the database connectors in the application code are going to connect to a well-known port, it would be very difficult to deploy this multi-db setup without some very special NAT trickery.

Comment: You need 3 links --link dbA:dbA --link dbB:dbB --link dbC:dbC and then configure your application in order to access each db on a different host. dbA:PORT dbB:PORT dbC:PORT. They are using all the same port because they are running on a different host. It's like connecting to three servers. Your application code should be able to handle three data sources easily.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sounds like a reasonable solution. My only other concern with this approach is the obvious duplication of database processes on my host.

Comment: To me this actually feels like an advantage from a security perspective, issues with one instance won't propagate to issues in the other.

Comment: I just realized the memory consumption on my server is getting unwieldy due to having separate mysqld instances for each app :( With default configuration, each mysql instance consumes about 400MB of memory.  This is another reason I wanted to stick with a single instance of mysqld and have pluggable databases with pluggable sources of data.